# How to calculate interpregnancy interval by mother ID?

Tags: r, date, time, intervals

I am trying to calculate pregnancy interval between births for each mother in my data set, using mother ID, in R.

This would be taking into account that a mother could have multiple births (i.e 2 births or 10 births), however, some of the pregnancies could have ended in miscarriage or stillbirth. In addition, some of the pregnancies could be multiple (i.e twins, triplets), as is the case of mother with ID 3.

Below is an example of the dataset.

| Mother_ID | Last*mentrual*period | Birth_date | Nr_fetuses | Preg_outcome | Gestational_age | Child_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1996-04-15 | 1996-12-08 | 1 | Livebirth | 237 | C1 |
| 2 | 2018-06-01 | 2019-02-18 | 1 | Livebirth | 262 | C2 |
| 3 | 2002-08-23 | 2003-05-07 | 1 | Livebirth | 257 | C3 |
| 3 | 1998-04-22 | 1999-01-15 | 2 | LiveBirth | 268 | C4 |
| 3 | 1998-04-22 | 1999-01-15 | 2 | Livebirth | 268 | C5 |
| 3 | 1992-02-21 | 1992-11-22 | 1 | Livebirth | 275 | C6 |
| 4 | 2006-02-28 | 2006-11-18 | 1 | Livebirth | 263 | C7 |
| 4 | 2003-01-31 | 2003-11-12 | 1 | Livebirth | 285 | C8 |
| 4 | 2005-01-04 | 2005-03-18 | 1 | Miscarriage | 73 |  |
| 5 | 2009-04-08 | 2009-06-06 | 1 | Miscarriage | 59 |  |
| 5 | 2009-08-01 | 2010-05-02 | 1 | Stillbirth | 274 | C9 |
| 6 | 1992-02-02 | 1992-09-05 | 1 | Stillbirth | 216 |  |
| 6 | 1995-02-21 | 1995-11-13 | 1 | Livebirth | 265 | C10 |
| 6 | 1990-02-08 | 1990-11-07 | 1 | Livebirth | 272 | C11 |

The outpout would show the pregnancy intervals, in days, ordered by date of birth for each mother.
Please could you suggest ways of achieving this, ideally with base R.

The output would be something like this:

| Line | Mother_ID | Last*mentrual*period | Birth_date | Nr_fetuses | Preg_outcome | Gestational_age | Child_ID | Inter_preg_inter (days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1996-04-15 | 1996-12-08 | 1 | Livebirth | 237 | C1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2018-06-01 | 2019-02-18 | 1 | Livebirth | 262 | C2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1992-02-21 | 1992-11-22 | 1 | Livebirth | 275 | C6 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1998-04-22 | 1999-01-15 | 2 | LiveBirth | 268 | C4 | 1977 |
| 5 | 3 | 1998-04-22 | 1999-01-15 | 2 | Livebirth | 268 | C5 | 1977 |
| 6 | 3 | 2002-08-23 | 2003-05-07 | 1 | Livebirth | 257 | C3 | 1316 |
| 7 | 4 | 2003-01-31 | 2003-11-12 | 1 | Livebirth | 285 | C8 | 0 |
| 8 | 4 | 2005-01-04 | 2005-03-18 | 1 | Miscarriage | 73 |  | 419 |
| 9 | 4 | 2006-02-28 | 2006-11-18 | 1 | Livebirth | 263 | C7 | 347 |
| 10 | 5 | 2009-04-08 | 2009-06-06 | 1 | Miscarriage | 59 |  | 0 |
| 11 | 5 | 2009-08-01 | 2010-05-02 | 1 | Stillbirth | 274 | C9 | 56 |
| 12 | 6 | 1990-02-08 | 1990-11-07 | 1 | Livebirth | 272 | C11 | 0 |
| 13 | 6 | 1992-02-02 | 1992-09-05 | 1 | Stillbirth | 216 |  | 452 |
| 14 | 6 | 1995-02-21 | 1995-11-13 | 1 | Livebirth | 265 | C10 | 899 |

So:
Pregnancy interval =Date of the last birth(line4) - Date of most recent birth (line3) - gestational age (i.e Mother_ID 3--->1999-01-15 - 1992-11-22 - 268 =1977 days)

OR

Pregnancy interval =Date of the last menstrual period(line4) - Date of most recent birth (line3) (i.e Mother_ID 3 ---> 1999-01-15 - 1992-11-22 =1977 days).

Sorted by mother ID and order of birth.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user21037671 Could you please provide what the final output would look like? In other words, what would the pregnancy intervals be for each mother in the example above? This will be very helpful to have and ensure logic needed for the calculations.

Comment: thanks @Ben! Example added and hopefully the query is clear now. Many thanks!

Comment: @user21037671 Please see answer below, let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: @Ben This is extremely helpful and it does indeed helping moving forward! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you moving forward - though there may be certain circumstances you'd want to modify further (e.g., twins where only old child survives, or multiple births spread out on consecutive dates past midnight, etc.).

First, you can sort your data by `Birth_date` and group by `Mother_ID`. You can create a pregnancy number to count pregnancies and allow for grouping, where the same "pregnancy" would be when the `Birth_date` is not more than 1 day apart.

Then, grouping by both `Mother_ID` and this new pregnancy number `Preg_num`, keep only one row of data (ignore that one or more children would be omitted, for now). After that, group again by `Mother_ID` and calculate intervals between pregnancies.

Finally, you can `right_join` back to the original data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df$Birth_date <- as.Date(df$Birth_date)

df %>%
  arrange(Mother_ID, Birth_date) %>%
  group_by(Mother_ID) %>%
  mutate(Preg_num = cumsum(Birth_date - lag(Birth_date, default = first(Birth_date)) > 1) + 1) %>%
  group_by(Mother_ID, Preg_num) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(Mother_ID) %>%
  mutate(Inter_preg_inter = ifelse(
    Preg_num == 1,
    0,
    Birth_date - lag(Birth_date) - Gestational_age
  )) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-c(Preg_outcome, Child_ID)) %>%
  right_join(df, by = c("Mother_ID", "Lastmentrualperiod", "Birth_date", "Nr_fetuses", "Gestational_age"))
```

**Output**

```
   Mother_ID Lastmentrualperiod Birth_date Nr_fetuses Gestational_age Preg_num Inter_preg_inter Preg_outcome Child_ID
       <int> <chr>              <date>          <int>           <int>    <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>        <chr>   
 1         1 1996-04-15         1996-12-08          1             237        1                0 Livebirth    C1      
 2         2 2018-06-01         2019-02-18          1             262        1                0 Livebirth    C2      
 3         3 1992-02-21         1992-11-22          1             275        1                0 Livebirth    C6      
 4         3 1998-04-22         1999-01-15          2             268        2             1977 LiveBirth    C4      
 5         3 1998-04-22         1999-01-15          2             268        2             1977 Livebirth    C5      
 6         3 2002-08-23         2003-05-07          1             257        3             1316 Livebirth    C3      
 7         4 2003-01-31         2003-11-12          1             285        1                0 Livebirth    C8      
 8         4 2005-01-04         2005-03-18          1              73        2              419 Miscarriage  NA      
 9         4 2006-02-28         2006-11-18          1             263        3              347 Livebirth    C7      
10         5 2009-04-08         2009-06-06          1              59        1                0 Miscarriage  NA      
11         5 2009-08-01         2010-05-02          1             274        2               56 Stillbirth   C9      
12         6 1990-02-08         1990-11-07          1             272        1                0 Livebirth    C11     
13         6 1992-02-02         1992-09-05          1             216        2              452 Stillbirth   NA      
14         6 1995-02-21         1995-11-13          1             265        3              899 Livebirth    C10
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Mother_ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Lastmentrualperiod = c("1996-04-15", 
"2018-06-01", "2002-08-23", "1998-04-22", "1998-04-22", "1992-02-21", 
"2006-02-28", "2003-01-31", "2005-01-04", "2009-04-08", "2009-08-01", 
"1992-02-02", "1995-02-21", "1990-02-08"), Birth_date = structure(c(9838, 
17945, 12179, 10606, 10606, 8361, 13470, 12368, 12860, 14401, 
14731, 8283, 9447, 7615), class = "Date"), Nr_fetuses = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Preg_outcome = c("Livebirth", 
"Livebirth", "Livebirth", "LiveBirth", "Livebirth", "Livebirth", 
"Livebirth", "Livebirth", "Miscarriage", "Miscarriage", "Stillbirth", 
"Stillbirth", "Livebirth", "Livebirth"), Gestational_age = c(237L, 
262L, 257L, 268L, 268L, 275L, 263L, 285L, 73L, 59L, 274L, 216L, 
265L, 272L), Child_ID = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", 
"C7", "C8", NA, NA, "C9", NA, "C10", "C11")), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```